# mediasoup webRTC Remote video stream showing blank on ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, webrtc, mediasoup

I have developed a Video chat application using angular , node.js , webRTC , mediasoup with pipe transport .
The remote video streams are working fine on localhost but they are not working after deployment to Ubuntu server .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpFaf.png)

Can anyone help in that ?

Why remote video stream is not working after deployment to server ?

Comment: You need to leave a lot more details about what you are trying to do.  Additional things like are the url's correct, have you looked at any error logs?  are you outputting any messages yourself?  are you hosting the ubuntu or is in the cloud?  are you behind a fire wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you open rtcMinPort & rtcMaxPort both for TCP/UDP connection. Make sure your firewall not blocking rtcPorts range : rtcMinPort:rtcMaxPort e.g if in my case rtcMinPort is 40000 & rtcMaxPort is 40100, i will make sure firewall is not blocking 40000:40100